# Role Based Access Control, Where Roles Change Depending on Location In Application

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication, windows, rbac

I am tasked with designing a new, role based access model for our system.

The requirements are something to the effect of the following:

1. A user can log in, and will have a different role depending on which client s/he is viewing.

   - This part is easy: Client A -> Project Manager, Client B -> QA Analyst, etc.
2. The user can be part of teams.

   - User A (member of) Team 1, Team 2, etc.
3. Here is the difficult part, in my mind.  Depending on which project is being viewed, the user can be assigned totally new roles.

   - Client A --> Project Manager is User A's real role, but for Project 1337, User A will be a QA Analyst.

Is there a good, coherent model to handle all of this, or will I need to create my own?

Comment: the answer is no.

Comment: in reality the answer is yes but have fun doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like it is going to be that easy since it doesn't look like you'd be able to take advantage of nesting groups if the projects are all isolated from each other, and users are going to have vastly different roles in each project.  I'd recommend labeling the groups with the project number/name AND role in the group name.  For example:

- Project 1 PM
- Project 1 QA
- Project 2 PM
- Project 2 QA
- etc...

In this way User A could be a member of Project 1 PM group and Project 2 QA group and have access based on those memberships.

I'm not quite sure what the purpose of the teams are or if you'd like to break access/notifications down by team or not so that might require a little more thought.